# Isomorphism between $H^1(\mathbb{P}^n,\mathcal{O}^*)$ and $H^2(\mathbb{P}^n,\mathbb{Z})$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, complex-geometry, projective-space, sheaf-cohomology

In Griffiths and Harris "Principles of Algebraic Geometry" in page 145 they write

$$Pic(\mathbb{P}^n)\simeq H^2(\mathbb{P}^n,\mathbb{Z})=\mathbb{Z}$$

and they justify it by saying $H^1(\mathbb{P}^n,\mathcal{O})=0$.

I have two questions:

- They are sending to a nonexistent reference such as Chapter 1 section 7. Where is the real one?
- Second, for the isomorphism to be true we need also the second cohomology group to vanish, that is $H^2(\mathbb{P}^n,\mathcal{O})=0$  as well. Is that correct? If yes where could I find a reference for that?

Thanks is advance.

Comment: You don't need the second cohomology group to vanish, this is only a sufficient condition. Here you can easily show that the map $c_1:\operatorname{Pic}(\mathbb{P}^n)\to H^2(\mathbb{P}^n,\mathbb{Z})$ is onto.

Comment: @Roland  I do not understand, if the isomorphism is true then for sure $H^2$ vanishes (by definition of the long exact sequence), are you suggesting another way to prove it using the chern class morphism $c_1$?

Comment: If $A\to B\to C$ is exact, then $A\to B\oplus X\to C\oplus X$ also is, so no, the vanishing of the $H^2$ is not necessary.

Comment: But, in any case $H^2(\mathbb{P}^n, O)$ vanishes, the cohomology of the projective space is generated by the 1st chern class of the tautological line bundle (or equivalently the class of a hyperplane).

Comment: Yes but the cohomology of $\mathcal{O}(1)$ is not the same as the cohomology of $\mathcal{O}$. @Ahr is right, $H^2(\mathbb{P}^n,\mathcal{O})=0$ for any $n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if it worth as an answer but...

Both questions are solved with the so called *Bott-formulae* A particular case can be found at the top of page 108 (section 7 of **Chap 0**) of Griffiths & Harris. This is as follows:

> **Bott Formulae:**
>   $$ \dim {\rm H}^q(\mathbb{P}^n, \Omega^p_{\mathbb{P}^n}\otimes \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n}(k)) = \begin{cases} \binom{k+n-p}{k}\binom{k-1}{p} &  {\rm for }\quad q=0,\, 0\leq p \leq n,\, k>p\\
> 1 & {\rm for }\quad k=0,\, 0\leq p =q\leq n\\ 
> \binom{p-k}{-k}\binom{-k-1}{n-p} &  {\rm for }\quad q=n,\, 0\leq p \leq n,\, k<p-n\\
> 0 &  {\rm otherwise }\end{cases}
> $$

This result can be found in [Okonek, Schneide, Splinder - Vector Bundles on Complex Projective Spaces](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783034801508) page 8.

The result in Griffiths & Harris is the particular case where $k=0$.

Answer (score 1):

You can show the relevant cohomology groups vanish using Hodge theory. Letting $h^{p,q}=\dim_{\mathbb C}H^q(\mathbb P^n,\Omega^p)$ and $b^i=\dim_{\mathbb C}H^i(\mathbb P^n,\mathbb C)$, we get the following (among other things)
\begin{align*}
b^1 = h^{0,1}+h^{1,0} && b^2=h^{0,2}+h^{1,1}+h^{2,0} && h^{0,2}=h^{2,0}
\end{align*}
At the same time, we know that $b^1=0$, so $h^{0,1}=h^{1,0}=0$, and that $b^2=1$. Since $h^{0,2}=h^{2,0}$, this means that $h^{1,1}=1$ and $h^{0,2}=0=h^{2,0}$. In particular, we've shown that
\begin{align*}
0=h^{0,1}=\dim H^1(\mathbb P^n, \mathscr O) && 0=h^{0,2}=\dim H^1(\mathbb P^n,\mathscr O)
\end{align*}
so we get the desired isomorphism $H^1(\mathbb P^n,\mathscr O^*)\to H^2(\mathbb P^n,\mathbb Z)$.